# JQuery UI dialog modal caching old values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-ui

I'm having a big problem using using Jquery dialog. The dialog is displayed when the user clicks on a link. The first time the form is opened, it works fine; the form is submitted to the server,
 and the part of the page is updated.However, subsequent attempts to use the form are where the problems start. When i click on the hyperlink for the second time, 
 (with closing dialog or without closing dialog), it is showing the old values. This happens even if I navigate to a different screen in the application and then return. 
The content of the page which is re-rendered after each submission includes the form which makes up the dialog, 
so the 'old' values which are being submitted no longer even exist in the page markup. 
They are being somehow 'remembered' by JQuery UI.

```
$(document).on("click", "#hyperLink", function () {
        $("#divSection").dialog({
            title: "User Details",
            resizable: false,
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 300,
            appendTo: "form" 
 });
 });
```

I don't know how to work around this behaviour, can anyone please help me how to resolve this?

Comment: You need to clear whatever is inside your dialog when closing it, or just before opening it.

Comment: Are you using `.dialog("close")` when you should be using `.dialog("destroy")`

Comment: Can you please provide me any sample code? i would like to clear when i'm opening the dialog..! 
$('#divSection').remove();        
        $("#divSection").dialog({ .................}); I

Comment: show us the code where you're closing the dialog.

Comment: I don't have any code/events when i'm closing the dialog.. that's what i'm looking to implement to fix this problem

Comment: They're not being stored by jQuery. A jQuery dialog is simply markup in the page, and the browser caches that. How are you updating the dialog contents?

Comment: Dialog content will be updated when i click on "save" button to submit the form to the server.. btw i'm working on asp.net @isherwood